# Why is Numpy vstack not working in this function

Tags: python, numpy

I have an issue with np.vstack that has been tripping me up.

Initially I used the following block of code repeatedly (and successfully):

```
   dev_data_blurred = []
     
   # Apply kernel to dev_data
   for img in dev_data:
     blurred_img = apply_kernel(img, .5)
     if len(dev_data_blurred) > 0:
       dev_data_blurred = np.vstack([dev_data_blurred, blurred_img])
     else:
       dev_data_blurred.append(blurred_img)
```

I decided to move this functionality to the following function with an example function call:

```
def get_blurred_data_struct(image_data, weight):
     data_blurred = []
          
     for img in image_data:
       blurred_img = apply_kernel(img, .5)
     if len(data_blurred) > 0:
       data_blurred = np.vstack([data_blurred, blurred_img])
     else:
       data_blurred.append(blurred_img)
     
     return data_blurred

dev_data_blurred = get_blurred_data_struct(dev_data, .5)
```

For some reason the np.vstack does not seem to be working in my function. I have messed with it for a good hour now, and the function  consistently returns a single 1D array, instead of an np.array of shape 1000,784 ( which is what I expect and get if I just perform the top block outside of a function). Any ideas?

Comment: Usually we recommend using list append to collect arrays in a loop, and doing `vstack` (or other array concatenate) at the end on the whole list.  Much less copying, and easier to get right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an indentation issue.

```py
     for img in image_data:
       blurred_img = apply_kernel(img, .5)
```

This always writes apply_kernel(img, .5) into the same variable. Due to your code vstack will never be called. So what you end up with is getting back a list that contains a single image. What you actually want to return I guess is

```py
def get_blurred_data_struct(image_data, weight):
    return np.vstack([apply_kernel(img, .5) for img in image_data])
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the help. That is pretty obvious in hind site.